# Shift dictionary values and swap them but not randomly

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Dictionary I am starting with is:

```
s={'A' : 'A', 'B' : 'B', 'C' : 'C'}
```

Dictionary I want to end up with is:

```
{'A' : 'B', 'B' : 'C', 'C' : 'A'}.
```

The only thing I know is how to get random letters instead of the one I have on some particular position, but in this problem I have to shift key's values by `n=1`.

I have tried to define `n` by which values are shifted but I end up with an error.

```
import string
dictionary = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)

def shift(dictionary,s)
    s2=' '
    for c in s:
          n=ord(c) - 65
          n=+=1
          n%=26
          s2+=chr(n+65)
    return s2
```

Comment: What version of python? Dictionaries are [not ordered before version 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744). Are you relying on sorting the keys by alphabetical order?

Comment: 3.7. I want to move each key to the next

Comment: how do you define "next". Is it by insertion order? Is it lexicographical order?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) and what you're actually looking for is `dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_uppercase[1:] + string.ascii_uppercase[0]))`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python 3.6+, then try this :

```
from collections import deque
s={'A' : 'A', 'B' : 'B', 'C' : 'C'}
rotated_values = deque(s.values())
rotated_values.rotate(-1)
new_s = {k:v for k,v in zip(s, rotated_values)}
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
{'A': 'B', 'B': 'C', 'C': 'A'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using OrderedDict's to ensure that your dictionary retains it's ordering when iterating.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
input_dictionary = OrderedDict(A="A", B="B", C="C")
values = list(input_dictionary.values())
for index, key in enumerate(iter(input_dictionary.keys())):
    new_value_index = (index + 1) % len(values)
    input_dictionary[key] = values[new_value_index]
print(input_dictionary)
```

Which gives you OrderedDict([('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A')])

Hope that helps